# Transformation In Clip Path Coordinates

Tags: css, svg

Any idea why the rotation does not seem to take place in the clip path coordinates?  `0.5 0.5` should denote the center of the shape, i.e. where the two squares meet.

```css
svg {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <clipPath id="rel" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform="rotate(20 0.5 0.5)">
    <rect width="0.5" height="0.5"/>
    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="0.5" height="0.5"/>
  </clipPath>
  <rect width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" clip-path="url(#rel)" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

I expected to see something like this:

```css
svg {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <clipPath id="abs" transform="rotate(20 50 50)">
    <rect width="50" height="50"/>
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50"/>
  </clipPath>
  <rect width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" clip-path="url(#abs)" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Why? Because that's how the SVG specification says it should work.

Comment: You can either apply the transformation (transform="rotate(20 0.5 0.5)") to each rect inside the clipPath or wrap the clipped rect in a group and transform the group with transform="rotate(20 50 50)"

Comment: @RobertLongson where does it say that?  I can only find "User agents must support the transform property and presentation attribute as defined in [css-transforms-1]" but there are no `clipPathUnits` in CSS, so I wouldn't know how to interpret this in the context?  My assumption was just that the transform takes place in the same coordinate system as everything else inside the element, is this not reasonable?